# VB6 how to consume a VB.NET array of Objects?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a VB.NET Dll, registered as COM interoperability, that exposes something like this:

```
Class Society
```

with a:

```
Property ListPersons As Person()
```

This is the VB.NET Code:

```
Public Class Society
    ...
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Person", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>  _
    Public Property ListPersons() As Person()
        Get
            Return Me.ListPersonsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.ListPersonsField = value
            Me.RaisePropertyChanged("ListPersons")
        End Set
    End Property
```

I have to fill that list with VB6 but I cannot find the way

Comment: Do you have any VB6 code that you tried? Can you add it? And what goes wrong with it, how does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this issue a lot in the past and to be honest I could not find a solution to pass an array of object.

One of the solutions I used in the past was to pass the data of the single object as parameters and then create the object in the .net DLL and add it to your list.

Example

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IPersonAdd

    <OperationContract()>
    Function AddPerson(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean

End Interface

Public Function AddPerson(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal value As Integer)
    Dim p as new Person(id, value)
    ListPersons.Add(p)
End Function
```